# How to Fix Error 400 (OAuth2 error) in case you enrolled for the Advanced Protection Program on Gsuite?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am enrolled for the Advanced Protection Program on my GSuite corporate account
I am getting attached error every time when I am trying to install/add any of the add-ons into google docs, sheets even it won't allow me to configure my Gmail account in outlook

does anyone has an idea of how to fix this thing after activation of google advance protection program

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue you can either enable the API or whitelist the application. To whitelist an application you’ll need the client ID value which you can get by clicking the ‘Request Details’ option in the 400 error message. Once you have the Client ID you can learn how to whitelist it here https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en.: